# how to load crystal report while button click using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a code to load crystal report while clicking a button in vb.net but it gives load failed error please help me to solve this .

my code is

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class ClinicianListRpt

Private reportDocument As New ReportDocument()
Dim paramField As New ParameterField()
Dim paramFields As New ParameterFields()
Dim paramDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
Private Sub ClinicianListRpt_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = False

    reportDocument.Load("ClinicianList.rpt")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument
    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "manager", "172.16.7.8", "SPEECH")
End Sub
End Class
```

thank you in advance

geetha

Comment: **1)** You have to specify the correct path to the rpt file in this code reportDocument.Load("ClinicianList.rpt")   **2)** CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument appears twice in code.      Post the exact error message and at which line of the code error appears

Comment: actually my report is in solution folder only. i am getting error in line reportDocument.Load("ClinicianList.rpt")
can i give exact path like reportDocument.Load("d:\speech\ClinicianList.rpt")

Comment: ya right vcs give exact path its working thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

VB Solutions runs from  **"YourSolutionFolder"/Bin/Debug** or **"YourSolutionFolder"/Bin/Release** depending on your configuration.

Hence your **rpt** file must exist in those folders.

Copy your **ClinicianList.rpt** files to above folder and then **reportDocument.Load("ClinicianList.rpt")** will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"))
```